# Auto adding textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I wanna ask for your opinions/ideas about how to automatically add new `Textbox` when user click on Add button. In my system, there are 2 Textboxes which user need to enter expenses and price respectively. And there's also a ADD button. When they click on it, another two boxes will automatically generate. Before this, I only have 8 Textboxes for expenses and 8 Textboxes for their price. But it looks quite messy for me so i want to make it more tidy. Thank you

Comment: use grid instead of manually adding textboxes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid and then have a hidden row that has the same input cells as the other rows.  When the add button is clicked, have javascript clone the hidden row and then add then show it, and add it to the bottom of the grid.

If a grid isn't right for your UI then do the same thing with just cloning a text box and showing it.  It is often easier to just have a single hidden input field with the proper style applied and then clone it, and then remove the display: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

> But it looks quite messy for me so i want to make it more tidy.

1. **[GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** should be used to make it visibility better and consume space properly.
2. Assign the DataSource to your **[GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**
3. Set the Text boxes in your **[Footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.footerstyle.aspx)**
4. When you click the `Add Button`,  Set the Visibility of your Footer "True"
5. Once user fills the values in Textbox save it and Bind to the **[GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.
6. Repeat Step 4 to iterate the same process next time.